# Transform DataFrame for Bar Chart Race

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, cumsum

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
Player | Team | Total_Points
  A       1         50
  B       2         75
  C       3         40
  A       1         45
  D       3         150
```

There are x players in n teams, and no player is in more than one team. I want to do a bar chart race by player and by team (Top 10 players bar chart race, n teams bar chart race). I want each occurrence of a team to count as a step.

I assumed the next step would be to transform the DataFrame into something like this for each row in the original dataframe (if doing team bar chart):

```
Team_1_CumSum | Team_2_CumSum | Team_3_CumSum | Team_4_CumSum |
     50               0               0               0        
     50              75               0               0
     50              75              40               0
     95              75              40               0
     95              75             190               0
```

After this, I would do the bar chart race.

Any ideas on how to:

1. Do the transformation
2. Bar Chart Race after

For the transformation, I tried:

```
df = df.groupby(['Team', 'total_points']).sum().groupby(level=0).cumsum().reset_index()
```

Have not yet got to the bar chart part. Any ideas? :)

EDIT:

The answer by Scott Boston works! The issue ended up being that I have 2000+ rows and the animation was too long. What I want to do now is:

```
Player | Team | Total_Points | Match_Number 
  A       1         50              1
  B       2         75              1 
  C       3         40              2
  A       1         45              2
  D       3         150             3
```

And instead of grouping the cumulative sum as listed in the original question, I want to group by Team and Match, so the steps are smaller.

```
Team_1_CumSum | Team_2_CumSum | Team_3_CumSum | Team_4_CumSum | Match
     50              75               0               0           1
     95              75              40               0           2
     95              75             190               0           3
```

Basically, one row per match.

Comment: [This Medium post](https://towardsdatascience.com/bar-chart-race-in-python-with-matplotlib-8e687a5c8a41) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Cum Score'] = df.groupby('Team')['Total_Points'].cumsum()

df_chart = df.set_index('Team', append=True)['Cum Score'].unstack().ffill().fillna(0)
df_chart.columns='Team_'+df_chart.columns.astype(str)+'_CumSum'
df_chart = df_chart.reindex([f'Team_{i}_CumSum' for i in range(1,5)], axis=1, fill_value=0)
print(df_chart)
```

Output:

```
Team  Team_1_CumSum  Team_2_CumSum  Team_3_CumSum  Team_4_CumSum
0              50.0            0.0            0.0              0
1              50.0           75.0            0.0              0
2              50.0           75.0           40.0              0
3              95.0           75.0           40.0              0
4              95.0           75.0          190.0              0
```

Then look at using (https://pypi.org/project/bar-chart-race/).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bar_chart_race as bcr
bcr.bar_chart_race(df_chart, 'Teams.mp4', steps_per_period=5)
```

[image]

Comment: That works! Could you see the edit to the question? I had to tweak a couple of things.